# how to copy data from one matrix to another in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 matrices A and B of dim N*5 and N*4 respectively. I want copy all the data from matrix B to A.I used the comand

> A(1:4,:)=B(1:4,:)

I get Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. Why is that? Can Anyone tell me ?

Comment: You're trying to copy a 4x4 chunk into a 4x5 space, apparently.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : so data can't be copied in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up rows and columns (if the dimensions are Nx5 and Nx4). Try

```
A(:, 1:4) = B(:, 1:4)
```

Comment: Or even: `A(:,1:4) = B`